# Rewrite of query with correlated subquery in join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, cross-apply

I have the query below which I am trying to rewrite. I have tried window functions and OUTER APPLY but it is difficult for me to get the logical meaning exactly the same. It seems like the below method is the only method to implement the logic.

```
SELECT  ...
FROM  dbo.Customer T  
  LEFT  JOIN dbo.CustSegment A 
            ON A.KEYCOL=T.KEYCOL  
            AND  A.date1=(select max(A1.date1) FROM  dbo.CustSegment A1 WHERE A1.KEYCOL=T.KEYCOL AND A1.date1<=T.date1) 
            AND A.date2=(select max(A2.date2) FROM  dbo.CustSegment A2 WHERE A2.KEYCOL=T.KEYCOL AND A2.date1=A.date1);
```

Extra information: date1 is some "effective date" and date2 is "registered date".

Comment: did you mean  `A2.date1=A.date1`?  should that be `A2.date1<=A.date1` like the other join condition?

Comment: @Hogan: No in the second condition it is eqaulity. Only the the first condition contains <=. Not sure of the business logic but the query I am working on looks like that

Comment: @Hogan: I have added an extra comment in the question.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input data, expected output and the full query?

Answer (score 2):

I think this code should be equavalent:

```sql
SELECT  ...
FROM  dbo.Customer T  
OUTER APPLY (
       SELECT TOP 1 a.*
        FROM dbo.CustSegment A 
        WHERE A.KEYCOL=T.KEYCOL
        AND a.date1 <= t.date1  
        ORDER BY a.date1 DESC, a.date2 DESC
) zzz
```

Although, this kinda presumes you only want top row. If you want duplicates of dates then it won't work

Comment: Just tested both versions and the results are the same. When I was trying OUTER APPLY, my code was very similar to yours. Not sure why I did not get it over the finish line.

Comment: This code is not same -- unless the date1 and date2 are always the same -- if the dates are different than the logic in OP will produce different results (very easy to make a test case that shows this)

Comment: Yes your code tries to find the max of date1 and date2 with one TOP.

Comment: I will remove the "accept" to see what other versions people can write.